# Формат строки: заполнение символами

Tags: c#, строки, формат

Приветствую,

Немного не знаю как правильно поставить вопрос.

Возможно ли в C# форматировать строку указанной ширины с заполнением не пробелами, а любым символом?

Сейчас приходится делать примерно так:

```
using System;

class main
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string str = "foo";
        str = String.Format( "[{0,-7}]", str ).Replace(' ' , '_');

        Console.WriteLine( str );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей можно использовать [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/System.String.PadLeft(v=vs.110).aspx)/[PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
str = string.Format("[{0}]", str.PadRight(7, '_'));
```

Comment: @ixSciс: пасибо, примерно то, что нужно, и работает немного быстрее.